# Graphql application cannot load due to network error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

This is a .net core application with React and GraphQL. Each time I start the application, I get "Network Error: Failed to fetch" on the browser.  The errors on the console is in the image below.  Any ideas pls? [image]

Here is the response from the network tab on the browser
[image]

Comment: Check the network tab under DevTools and see what the actual response is from the server. The request itself is failing, but you won't be able to tell why just from that stack trace. Update your question with the details of the server response.

Comment: As a side note, is your server routing case-sensitive? I see the request being made is to `/graphQL`

Comment: graphQL is not case sensitive.  I changed it to graphql but the errors are the same.  I will post the response from the network tab shortly.